# Gridview TemplateField

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Preciso de alterar uma Célula especifica na `GridView`, mas quando o tento fazer deste modo no `RowDataBound`:

```
 TextBox x = ((TextBox)e.Row.Cells[i].FindControl("ctl" + tx.PadLeft(2,'0')))
 x.Enable = False;
```

ou desta forma;

```
((TextBox)e.Row.Cells[i].FindControl("ctl")).Enable = false;
```

ou desta:
    e.Rows[i].Cells[j].Enable = false;

Todo a coluna é afetada, alguem me consegue ajudar a alterar uma `cell` especifica de uma linha/coluna especifica.

A minha GridView Tem o seguinte HTML:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" Font-Size="XX-Small" ForeColor="#333333" Width="100%" HorizontalAlign="Center" PageSize="35" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#6E7265" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#BDC0C4" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" Wrap="True" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="1px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

No html não conseguem deslumbrar o templteeField porque ele é criado no código behind da seguinte forma:

```
 foreach (DataColumn col in x.Columns)
            {
                //Declare the bound field and allocate memory for the bound field.
                TemplateField bfield = new TemplateField();

                //Initalize the DataField value.
                bfield.HeaderTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Header, col.ColumnName);

                //Initialize the HeaderText field value.
                bfield.ItemTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Item, col.ColumnName);

                //Add the newly created bound field to the GridView.
                GridView1.Columns.Add(bfield);
            }
```

Comment: Em qual evento da gridview você está tentando alterar o valor da célula?

Comment: estou a tentar alterar no RowDataBound

Comment: Complemente sua pergunta com o HTML da `gridview`, acho que ficará mais fácil de entender.

Answer (score 1):

Se eu não me engano acho que era assim:

```
 DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = valorquevocêquiser;
```

Comment: O problema e que nessa localização tenho um textbox, e minha intenção é alterar o Enable da text apenas nessa celula.

Comment: Mas este text recebe algum ID??

Comment: sim recebe, "cl"+j  j e o numero de coluna

Comment: E não seria possível somente fazer esta alteração pelo ID ao invés da célula? Assim: textBox1.Enabled = false

Comment: sim, eu tento fazer pelo id, mas acabava por alterar toda a coluna.

Comment: Se você tentar aplicar pelo id, vocês aplicará um valor para todos os TextBox que tem o mesmo Id. Essa alteração, para que ocorra de forma individual (por célula), deve ser feita no RowDataBound.

Comment: é onde a realizo a alteração

Comment: É foi o que suspeitei, eu tive um problema assim montando um relatório de documentação de desenvolvimento e fiz com o gridView. E realmente eu conheço este código aqui e era para funcionar: ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].FindControl("txtPerguntaRepeater")).Enable = valor

Comment: como resolveu o problema?

Comment: Fiz tudo na mão sem GridView fui montando no html os resultados um a um. Criando a tabela na mão. É que como tinha prazo e eu trazia as informações de um DB de Sharepoint, então tive que fazer gambiarra! :P

Comment: Penso que deve existir uma forma melhor de se fazer isso. O problema é que é uma tabela dinamica

Comment: Sim e acho que você está no caminho, mas é complicado usar gridView, espero nunca precisar dependendo do desenvolvimento solicitado.

Answer (score 1):

Talvez o seu problema esteja no momento da renderização do TextBox.

Fiz um exemplo com os dados que você enviou (HMTL + C#). Nesse exemplo, alterei a forma de adicionar campos customizados a `gridview`. Veja a seguir:

O mesmo HTML da gridview que você enviou, mais a adição do campo customizado `txtCustom`.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" CellPadding="4" Font-Size="XX-Small" 
    ForeColor="#333333" Width="100%" HorizontalAlign="Center" PageSize="35" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="grid_RowDataBound">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#6E7265" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#BDC0C4" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" Wrap="True" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="1px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustom" runat="server" Text="Items" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

A captura do evento `RowDataBound`:

```
protected void grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var ctrl = e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("txtCustom") as TextBox;
        ctrl.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Repare no `if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)`. Essa verificação é necessário porque desejo alterar apenas as linhas de dados, estou ignorando o cabeçalho (header), o rodapé (footer), entre outros.

Comment: Sim mas o numero de colunas não é sempre igual. e dessa iria me alterar todas as linhas onde esse id aparece. O que é o meu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Pesquisei um pouco mais e percebi que você utilizou [este exemplo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.templatefield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) para criar as colunas dinamicamente na sua gridview.
Para encontrar o controle correto na célula, é necessário alguns passos:

**1.Aplicar um ID para o custom control no GridViewTemplate:**

```
public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
{
    // Create the content for the different row types.
    switch (templateType)
    {
        case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
            var textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.Text = "Default Value";
            textBox.Enabled = true;
            textBox.ID = "txtCustom";
            container.Controls.Add(textBox);
            break;

        default:
            // Insert code to handle unexpected values.
            break;
    }
}
```

No meu caso, utilizei apenas o DataRow, novamente, para adicionar um controle customizado.

**2.O HTML não sofre alteração:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" CellPadding="4" Font-Size="XX-Small" 
    ForeColor="#333333" Width="100%" HorizontalAlign="Center" PageSize="35" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="grid_RowDataBound">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#6E7265" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#BDC0C4" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" Wrap="True" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="1px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

**3. Você encontra o controle pelo nome em RowDataBound:**

```
protected void grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var ctrl = e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("txtCustom") as TextBox;
        ctrl.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Nesse caso, é necessário que você saiba qual é a coluna que o controle está. O `RowDataBound` navega linha por linha, então, você deve selecionar a linha que deseja alterar e a coluna.

Comment: Foram encontrados vários controlos com o mesmo ID 'txtValor'. FindControl requer que os controlos tenham ID exclusivos. Esta Solução continua a não funcionar

Comment: Mas você filtrou as linhas que deseja modificar os valores? O RowDataBound percorrerá todas as linha da gridview e para cada linha encontrará apenas um txtCustom na coluna 0 (considerando o exemplo que fiz).